# Train ML model with windowed data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

I'm trying to train ML model (currently in python - but it doesn't matter if a solution exists in other languages).

My main goal is to train a supervised ML model ( for now I'm testing SVM, SGD, RandomForestClassifier using scikit) to classify 1/0 on a window data frame.

**More details:**

let's assume I have a data frame shape (1000,3), I want every 100 samples and with 50 samples overlap will be a window

(for example :

window1: 0-100,

window2: 50-150,

etc..)

and the label is for each window and not for a single sample.
when I'm trying to insert to the Train function a list of lists as the samples its throws an error.
another solution I thought about is transforming the rows into columns but if so I will have 100 dimensions that don't sound a good idea ( dimension explosion ? ). and performing PCA can damage the results

The data frame is a kind of time- series but without a timestamp. we are using the sample num as the time-stamp so the order is matter.

Example of an attempt to train SVM.linearSVC model with windows as df:

```
testData = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(50, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
groups = [testData[i:i + 10].reset_index() for i in range(0, 50, 5)]
labels = np.random.randint(0,2,10)
single_svc_model_c10 = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.LinearSVC(C=10), n_jobs=-1)
single_svc_model_c10.fit(groups, labels)
```

this isn't the actual data but the arrays look like:

```
groups[0] = index A B C [0: 0 3 3 32], [1: 1 34 42 9], [2: 2 40 19 14], [3: 3 21 39 25], [4: 4 15 15 37], [5: 5 39 2 25], [6: 6 13 31 3], [7: 7 2 0 18], [8: 8 13 33 36], [9: 9 0 24 20]

groups[1] = index A B C [0: 5 39 2 25], [1: 6 13 31 3], [2: 7 2 0 18], [3: 8 13 33 36], [4: 9 0 24 20], [5: 10 10 20 6], [6: 11 40 39 21], [7: 12 37 31 35], [8: 13 22 35 36], [9: 14 6 44 20]

labels = [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
```

and the error is thrown:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 10 to array axis with dimension 4
```

**Remarks on the context:**

1. the data is labeled per row, for now, it can be manually handled per window.

2.we have more than 1M samples.

3.the model should be used to detect falling. the columns in the DataFrame are features and not raw values.

4. We are using python and Scikit for now. It's changeable Package or language-wise.

**Edit** part of the dataset:

[image: DataSet snippet]

**so my questions are:**

1. is it possible to train the ML model on a windowed data frame, and if so. **how?**
2. if transformation is needed, it isn't too much 100 columns and 4 rows ( to transform the rows and cols as described above)
3. is it even recommended to use SVM or other similar ML models on time-series data?
4. Another approach for classifying and modeling windowed data frames?

Thanks and stay safe everyone

Comment: Could you share a small part of your dataset?

Comment: @HenriqueBranco edited and added. Thanks

Comment: Check out seqlearn, it makes it easy to do windowed classification. https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn